# Can I assign signal to new object in destructor of old one by deleteLater()

Tags: python, event-handling, pyqt

I have got a scrollArea where are few buttons and frames
On click of a button

```
self.connect(self.day_btn, QtCore.SIGNAL("toggled(bool)"), self.show_days)
```

I call a function where i try delete all objects in scrollArea using deleteLater()

```
def show_days(self):      
    if self.day_btn.isChecked():
        if self.day_objs_list:
            for temp_day in self.day_objs_list:

                self.day_objs_list[temp_day]['frame'].deleteLater()
```

and after that create new frames in this function and need to apply self.scrollArea.ensureWidgetVisible()

but looks like it was applyed for old (deleted) objects and only after that it creates new objects

as i understood from [Does deleteLater() wait for all pending signals to be delivered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863629/does-deletelater-wait-for-all-pending-signals-to-be-delivered)

When you emit a signal, it is placed in the event queue. Calling deleteLater also adds an event to the queue

How can I add in function signal that will work after deleteLater()
simple emit does not work. It makes ensureWidgetVisible() works but for old objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete an object immediately by using the [sip module](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/python_api.html):

```
import sip
...

sip.delete(self.day_objs_list[temp_day]['frame'])
```

Comment: Tried to do it with sip, but the same problem still remains
after creating new frames in this function self.scrollArea.ensureWidgetVisible() doesnot work

looks like it was applyed for old (deleted) objects and only after that it creates new objects

Comment: I think so happens because event loop creates new frames; And i need something that will start self.scrollArea.ensureWidgetVisible() after creation of new frames

Comment: @ВиталийБелоусов. It's got nothing to do with the event loop. Using `sip.delete` is the right way to do it. There are probably other issues with your code that you are not showing. Please edit your question and add a more realistic example that shows how you are creating and deleting all the widgets.